# Spring controllers not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am unable to call spring MVC controller. Everytime I hit it, it says not found. 
My files are as following.

Web.xml

```
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/gk1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gkool" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>
```

My controller file

```
package com.gkool;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/score")
public class ScoreController {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ScoreController.class);
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(@PathVariable("name") String name) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("hello");
        model.addObject("msg", name);

        return model;

    }

}
```

when I start sever and hit URL http://localhost:8080/gk1/score or http://localhost:8080/gk1/score/hello/anoop It gives error code 404 not found.

P.S. /gk1 is module name in tomcat.

When I start the tomcat server it gives following logs

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/score/hello/{name}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.gkool.ScoreController.hello(java.lang.String)
Feb 07, 2017 10:37:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/score],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.gkool.ScoreController.printWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Feb 07, 2017 10:37:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
```

That means it identifies a mapped URL as /score/hello/{name} but when I start my server in debug and put a debugger breakpoint in the controller method, the debug control doesn't come there.

can anyone please help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a detailed DEBUG log output of the application startup and when you send those requests.

Comment: Just updated the question. Please read and let me know if you were able to understand it.

Comment: You've mapped your `DispatcherServlet` to `/gk1`. That's an exact match, It will only handle requests to `/gk1`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you've defined the context web within the tomcat configuration of your application:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/myapp.war" path="/myContext" reloadable="true"/>
```

Now execute the request like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myContext/gk1/score/hello/anoop
```

But if you've defined like:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/myapp.war" path="/gk1" reloadable="true"/>
```

Then in the web.xml servlet configuration you just have to define the servlet mapping like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your Spring configuration.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

is a configuration element.

This is required for Spring to "find" your controllers:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.controller.package"/>
```

Per the Sotirios Delimanolis comment, the following configuration

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gk1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Tells tomcat to send requests with exactly match this URL: `http://localhost:8080/gk1` to the spring servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gk1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Which tells tomcat to send any request that starts with the URL `http://localhost:8080/gk1` to spring.

The `*` is the difference between: "exactly match" and "starts with".

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. My server startup gives following log

 Mapped "{[/score/hello/{name}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.gkool.ScoreController.hello(java.lang.String)

That means it is identifying my controller methods but not able to hit it via browser.